# Adding a new Namenode to an existing HDFS cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In Hadoop HDFS Federation the latest step of adding a new NameNode to an existing HDFS cluster is:
==> *Refresh the Datanodes to pickup the newly added Namenode by running the following command against all the Datanodes in the cluster:*

```
[hdfs]$ $HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNameNodes <datanode_host_name>:<datanode_rpc_port>
```

Witch is the best place to execute the flowing command: NameNode or datanode ?
If I have 1000 Datanodes is it logical to run it 1OOO time ?

Comment: Is this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

In namenode run this command once.

```
$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/slaves.sh hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNameNodes <datanode_host_name>:<datanode_rpc_port>
```

`slaves.sh` script will distribute the command to all the slave hosts which are mentioned in `slaves` file (typically placed in `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`)

Comment: for the test you can do `slaves.sh jps` in namenode host. It'll list all processes in slave machines.

Comment: slaves.sh not found for me

Comment: It will be placed in `$HADOOP_INSTALL_DIR/sbin/`

Comment: Yes I found it but I can't run it. I get **command not found**

Comment: when I do : `$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/slaves.sh hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes` I get this error for every slave :  **refreshNodes: Access denied for user root. Superuser privilege is required**